# MVC2 Project Not Opening in VS2010 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, csproj

When i try to open MVC2 Project in visual studio 2010 SP1 Ultimate Version, it is not opening. It is saying error as `The project type is not supported by this installation.` Here is my `.csproj` file. What issues ? Any ideas would be helpful?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
   <ProductVersion>
   </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{33A3BB36-843A-463A-97EB-F9748043FA2B}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
   <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
   <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
   <RootNamespace>Dial4Jobz</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Dial4Jobz</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>false</UseIISExpress>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
   <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
   <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
    <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System" />
<Reference Include="System.Data" />
<Reference Include="System.Data.Entity" />
<Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
<Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
<Reference Include="System.Security" />
<Reference Include="System.Transactions" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.DynamicData" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
<Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Core">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Extensions">
  <RequiredTargetFramework>3.5</RequiredTargetFramework>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
<Reference Include="System.Xml" />
<Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
<Reference Include="System.Web.Services" />
<Reference Include="System.EnterpriseServices" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>

<Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
     <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Dial4Jobz.edmx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
</ItemGroup>
<Content Include="Web.config">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</Content>
<Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</Content>
<Content Include="Web.Release.config">
  <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
</Content>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<WCFMetadata Include="Service References\" />
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
<!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
   Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
</Target> -->
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
<AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>
<ProjectExtensions>
<VisualStudio>
  <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
    <WebProjectProperties>
      <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
      <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
      <DevelopmentServerPort>49951</DevelopmentServerPort>
      <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
      <IISUrl>
      </IISUrl>
      <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
      <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
      <CustomServerUrl>
      </CustomServerUrl>
      <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
    </WebProjectProperties>
    </FlavorProperties>
   </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
 </Project>
```

Comment: Downvoters care to comment... whats wrong with my question?

Comment: Did it work for you in the past, or have you never been able to open MVC2 projects?

Comment: No, I just got this project now. I never opened MVC2 project before in my laptop.

Comment: Did you install MVC2?

Comment: yes through `Microsoft Web Platform Installer` I installed `ASP.NET MVC2`